# add additional namespace to existing namespace using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement to get output as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02 camt.053.001.02.xsd">
```

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">
```

I have already tried the code but it is not working.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02 camt.053.001.02.xsd"
 xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/namespace::xsi"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/namespace::schemaLocation"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I also need to remove prefix ns0:.
Please help.

Comment: output should be <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02 camt.053.001.02.xsd">

Comment: input is: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">

Comment: Why not edit the question and provide there the source XML document, the wanted result and the rules for the transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you cannot do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02 camt.053.001.02.xsd">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Document>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael for your quick response. I tried your code but getting the original namespace repeating in the next node. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02 camt.053.001.02.xsd">
<ns0:BkToCstmrStmt xmlns:ns0="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">
<ns0:GrpHdr>

Comment: @swapnashree Please edit your question and add a [mcve] showing a representative example of your input and the expected output. Do not post code in comments.